# Cron job that calls a url for a rails app every 1 minute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, cron

I need a cron job to write into my crontab that every after one minute calls a URL of rails application that triggers a method and runs a scheduled job.

I did not use whenever gem because it reboots the environment and i think it will strain my application. So i preferred to run a full system cron job independent of the rails app.

The URL to be called is `https://xxxxxxxxx.com/scheduled_messages` preferably being called using `curl`.

The controller being called is ;

```
class SchedulesController < ActionController::Base
  def scheduled_messages
    Schedule.scheduled_jobs
    render nothing: true        
  end
end
```

and the method `Schedule.scheduled_jobs` is here;

```
def self.scheduled_jobs   
  jobs = Schedule.where('execution_time <= ?', Time.now)
    if !jobs.empty?
        jobs.each do |job|
         task = Schedule.find(job)
         MessageWorker.perform_async(task.message_id, task.lists, task.user_id)
         task.destroy
        end
      end
end
```

Comment: And what have you tried? It's not hard to write a cron job, nor is it hard to script tools like cURL or wget to hit a URL.

Comment: @ the Tin Man, i had written one but i had no experience. It looked like the one in the answer and i guess it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there are other ways to do this, the cron will look like:

`* * * * * /usr/bin/curl "https://xxxxxxxxx.com/scheduled_messages"`.

One of those other ways could be [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler).

Comment: rufus-scheduler was misbehaving and i thought i could do my way.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Sidekiq. Use Sidetiq for reccurring tasks. https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq